# Order the elements of array list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist defined whose elements are say, `[man, animal, bird, reptile]`. The elements in the arraylist are non-mandatory. The list can even be empty.

I always need to give the output as `[animal,man,reptile,bird]`. Means, the order of the elements are to be maintained. Is there any way of doing in arraylist?

I thought I can do like

```
for (String listElement: customList) { //custom list variable holds all elements
    if (listElement.equalsIgnoreCase("animal"){
        newList.add(0, listElement);
} else if("man") {
    newlist.add(1, listElement);
}
```

But I would want to know the best practice of doing. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? I don't see any obvious logic in your ordering example.

Comment: You can use `TreeSet` with a custom comparator. ;)

Comment: I want to order the elements in custom way. From [man, animal, bird, reptile] to [animal, man, reptile, bird]. The order is pre-defined.

Comment: @Poppy Does it follow a certain logic ?

Comment: @ZouZou No. Ther is no logic behind. It is just pre-defined order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom sorting and use it to order your array (save the comparator somewhere, so you don't have to instantiate it many times):

```
List<String> definedOrder = // define your custom order
    Arrays.asList("animal", "man", "reptile", "bird");

Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2){
        // let your comparator look up your car's color in the custom order
        return Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o1))
            .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o2)));
    }
};

Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom comparator:

```
    Collections.sort(customList, comparator);

    int i = 0;
    for (String temp : customList) {
        System.out.println("customList " + ++i + " : " + temp);
    }
```

Custom comparator below:

```
public static Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {        

    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return orderOf(str1) - orderOf(str2);
    }

    private int orderOf(String name) {          
            return ((List)Arrays.asList("animal", "man", "reptile", "bird")).indexOf(name);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new CustomComparator());`

You need to create your own comparator for this, though, but it is easy.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<YourType>{

    @Override
    public int compare(YoyrType o1, YoyrType o2) {
        // logic for ordering the list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arraylist is ordered.
maybe you want to insert element into the list.
could you create a new list every time when you have to insert and copy each of them?